# Multimeter resistance measure

Tags: resistors, measurement, multimeter

I've found this question but they don't talk about damage ([Multimeter ranges](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/51579/multimeter-ranges))

If I measure a 20KOhm resistance an I'm for example in the 200Ohm range, can this damage my multimeter ?

Comment: No! Not even shorting the leads will the meter. Nor will open leads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your multimeter will be fine. It will display that the resistance is infinite if the resistance is greater than the range. 
The reason you don't have to worry is because the multimeter is acting a constant current source, a very small one. So even if you short the probes, there will only be a small current flowing through them. 
Since it is a constant current source, it can measure the voltage across the probes as well. R = V/I, we know how much current we are pushing through the resistor and we are measuring the voltage across the resistor, therefore the multimeter knows the resistance.
That is how the resistance function of a conventional multimeter works.

Comment: To be precise, it will display the the resistance is *off-scale high*, not infinite.

Answer (score 2):

Not at all I would say. I can't think of any circumstances other than you trying to measure the value while hundreds of volts were across it. You should always ensure, when measuring in-circuit resistances that power supplies are either off or non-effective on that part of the circuit. This includes storage elements like batteries and capacitors - caps should be discharged BUT, it's still only high voltage still across a resistor that can damage the meter. Batteries or residual charge will make your reading nonsence but, in most circumstances won't damage the meter.